# CloudKit CoreAnimation error

Tags: cloudkit

We are beginning to work with CloudKit and have been working with Firebase for a while.

The issue we are having is a CoreAnimation warning when we are not using CoreAnimation in our code.

```
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
```

This occurs whenever we read/add/update/delete any record from CloudKit.

For example, here's our initial loading of Contacts into an NSTableView

```
-(void)loadContacts {

    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Contact" predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"]];

    self.arrayToDisplay = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self.publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        if ( error ) {

            NSLog(@"error loading array:  %@", error.localizedDescription);

        } else {

            self.arrayToDisplay.array = results; //arrayToDisplay is an array of CKRecord objects

            [self.myTableView reloadData];

        }

    }];

}
```

self.publicDatabase is an initialized CKDatabase.

Note that all the functions work, read/add/update/delete, but that message appears after each call.

We have set the CA_DEBUG to log the backtraces and it appears it's got something to do with redrawing the NSTableView before the records are fetched?

Comment: Found more info. It appears the completion block runs in a background thread so the call the reload the tableview also is in a background thread. How to fix that? Similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257952/cloudkit-query-time

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix the issue as it puts the tableView reload back onto the main thread. Just replace the [self.tableView reloadData] in the block with the following.

```
[self.tableView
    performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
    withObject:nil
    waitUntilDone:NO
];
```

Answer (score 0):

performSelectorOnMainThread: will work just fine as you posted in your answer.  However sometimes you want to do more than just execute a single method.  In that case I recommend wrapping multiple lines of code into a GCD dispatch statement.  Here's how it looks:

```
__weak UITableView *weakTableView; // use a weak reference to prevent retain cycle
dispatch_queue_t q_main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(q_main, ^() {
    [weakTableView reloadData];
    // do other stuff too if you want
});
```